# Is it possible to calculate AUC using OOB sample in Bagged trees?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, data-science

I have few questions on OOB sample in Bagged trees.
1.Do we always calculate only error on OOB samples? If yes, which error metric is used for evaluation(like rmse, misclassification err)?
2.Also, do we have this OOB concept in boosting also?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com is a better place to post this. https://stackoverflow.com is for Implementation questions about machine learning algorithms. General questions about machine learning should be posted to their specific communities.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to calculate AUC using OOB sample in Bagged trees?

- An ROC curve is the most commonly used way to visualize the performance of a binary classifier, and AUC is (arguably) the best way to summarize its performance in a single number. It does not matter wether you are using Bagged Trees or not. You can find a nice explanation [here](http://www.dataschool.io/roc-curves-and-auc-explained/)

1.Do we always calculate only error on OOB samples?

- Not necessarily, before bootstrapping, you can set aside validation set and do cross validation

If yes, which error metric is used for evaluation(like rmse, misclassification err)?

- If it is Regression problem, sum of squared errors(RSS) for the tree can be used
- For a Classification problem, Misclassification error rate can be used.

2.Also, do we have this OOB concept in boosting also?

- Let's see what is OOB ? The key to bagging is that trees are repeatedly fit to bootstrapped subsets of the observations.On average, each bagged tree makes use of around two-thirds of the observations.The remaining one-third of the observations not used to fit a given bagged tree are referred to as the out-of-bag (OOB) observations. [Reference: An Introduction to Statistical Learning, Section 8.2.1, Out-of-Bag Error Estimation](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)
- Boosting does not involve bootstrap sampling; instead each tree is fit on a modified version of the original data set. [Reference: An Introduction to Statistical Learning, Section 8.2.3](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)
- Therefore going by the definition,OOB concept is not applicable for Boosting.
- But note that most implementation of Boosted Tree algorithms will have an option to set OOB in some way. Please refer to documentation of respective implementation to understand their version.

Comment: Thanks Arun! Any idea how the OOB error gets calculated for bagged trees(this is my first question)?